# How can I access the last read in variable in scanf?

Tags: c, scanf

I am programming (atleast trying heh) a function that you can read in floats or integer etc. and that checks if it is a valid input by the user. So I wrote this code this far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int scancheck (const char *fmt, ...) {
    int count, check, x = 1;
    size_t len = strlen(fmt);
    char *newfmt = malloc(len + 1 + 1 + 1);
    strcpy(newfmt, fmt);
    newfmt[len] = '%';
    newfmt[len + 1] = 'c';
    newfmt[len + 1 + 1] = '\0';
    va_list ap;
    do {
        va_start (ap, newfmt);
        check = (count = vfscanf(stdin, newfmt, ap));
        if (check != strlen(newfmt) / 2) {
            printf("Error\n");
            fflush(stdin);
        } else {
            x = 0;
        }
        va_end (ap);
    } while (x);
    return count;
}
```

It works and I can read in numbers, depending on the format string that I use when calling the function. However there is one big problem:
If I enter a letter AFTER the number, it is accepted. So I extended the format string with %c. Now I want to check if it is equal to '\n', i.e. if you hit the Enter key at last. However I don't know how I can do that, as I can't access that variable, as it is not saved anywhere AND I don't know how I can save it.
I hope that you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: debugger is the answer

Comment: You can't add `%c` to the format string if you don't also add a variable to the argument list, since it's going to try to write the character somewhere.

Comment: Did you read the documentation of `vfscanf` ?

Comment: If you want line-based input, do line-based input.  That means using [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or POSIX's [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) to read the line and then `sscanf()` (or a relative — `vsscanf()` for you — to parse the data.  You still have problems knowing where the scanning ended.  You'd normally add `%n` to the format string and an extra `int *` to the argument list; that's not feasible with `va_list`.  I'm not sure there's a clean solution for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No simple way to add a variable to the list  [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41770787/how-can-i-access-the-last-read-in-variable-in-scanf/41771211#comment70733712_41770787), short of re-processing the entire `fmt`.

---

Suggest reading the trailing characters with `fgetc()` instead.

```
int scancheck (const char *fmt, ...) {
  va_list ap;
  va_start (ap, fmt);
  int count = vfscanf(stdin, fmt, ap);
  va_end (ap);

  if (count != EOF) {
    // consume all trailing characters in the line
    // Look for non-white-space
    int non_white_space = 0;
    int ch;
    while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF) {
      non_white_space |= !isspace(ch);
      if (ch == '\n') {
        break;
      }
    }

    if (non_white_space) {
      printf("Error\n");
      // or other error handling like `count = 0;`
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

---

Algorithmiker, I think we can use your germ of a nifty idea for how to, in general, use a `scanf()` like function and consume trailing characters including that pesky trailing `'\n'` and detect if any offending (non-white-space) characters were found.

Comment: Thank you. I used your code and changed it a bit. Now you have to enter a number as long as it is a proper input. You also made a mistake with the while-loop. The semicolon does not belong there.
I just have got one more question:
what does non_white_space |= !isspace(ch); mean? What I mean: What does that |= do?

Comment: @Algorithmiker `;` fixed.  `non_white_space |= !isspace(ch);` uses the _or_eq_ assignment operator. It is  similar to  `if (isspace(ch) == 0) non_white_space = 1;`.  Go with the style that works for you.